# How can I control which messages are considered focused, and other in Outlook?

Tags: outlook

The Focused inbox is handy in Outlook for hiding out all the dross emails like marketing emails, but some emails that require my action are ending up in there, and being missed until I read my email on a desktop PC.

How can I train the system to understand what emails I want to focus on (like invoices due payment) vs. those I don't (like an email inviting me to go to a meetup)?

Comment: Love to have some feedback on how this question could be improved by the person that chose to downvote

Comment: Someone had twitchy fingers ;-) not me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the messages (that are important to you) from Other inbox to the Focused inbox. Doing so will allow them, in the future, to be placed in the Focused inbox instead of the Other inbox.

To move a message from the Other inbox to the Focused inbox:

1. Select the Other tab, then long-press the message you want to move.
2. Click the 3-dot on the top right, select `Move to Focused inbox`

Comment: Ah, I'd tried the three dots on the message, and looked for options in the folder view, and didn't appreciate the second menu on the message